# Is there an API call to get all the sata hardware devices ?

Tags: windows, winapi, wdk

I  trying to get all the SATA  hardware devices that connected.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | Select Caption
```

You can pull the drive type from the resulting output.

Comment: But i need to device enumerate - how can i find it   ??

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should be able to do `Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | Select Index, Caption` to get the index for each drive.  Is that what you were trying to do?